# Multiple Email Accounts in Outlook 2007 / Exchange 2010

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I need to set up multiple email accounts in Outlook in addition to my primary Exchange account.

Is it possible to use our Exchange server as our outgoing mail server for the additional accounts?  If so, how do I configure the Outgoing mail server settings?

I do not know if it is relevant, but if I try to establish a Telnet session with our Exchange server, I get the following message

*220 mx1.emailsrvr.com ESMTP - VA Code Section 18.2-152.3:1 forbids sending spam through this system*

followed by

*Connection to host lost*

I have spent hours trawling the internet for an answer to this question, but either I have been searching on the wrong terms, or it hasn't been asked before.  As the latter is highly unlikely, I suspect the former to be the case, so any pointers will be most gratefully received!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to answer my own question.

In case anyone else has the same problem, what you are actually trying to do is to allow Exchange to act as a relay server.  You should find all the information you require here ...

*http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/set-multiple-email-identities-single-account*

I hope this helps someone.